BigDecimal - How to know the precision in small decimal numbers below 1 considering left zeroes just after comma
I am developing a calculator and I want to format the number in scientific notation only when it reaches a certain number of digits.
I wrote this piece of code which works fine for big numbers.
DecimalFormat df;
if (valorSaida.stripTrailingZeros().precision() > FOCalcConstants.MAX_DIGITOS) {
    df = new DecimalFormat("0.################E00");
} else {
    df = new DecimalFormat("#.###################");
}
String strSaida = df.format(valorSaida).replace('.', ',');

The MAX_DIGITOS constant is 20 and the scale of the BigDecimal variable valorSaida is also 20.
But with numbers such as 0.0000012345, the precision is aways 5, for example, so I can never get the real number of digits in decimal part of the number and therefore I can't format it in scientific notation.
The value is ever cut until reaches 0.00000000000000000001.
Can any one help me?
The scale() method is not useful in this case, because it aways returns the scale 20 as predefined in the BigDecimal variable.
I am looking for a solution without manipulation of digits as in a string.
I tried the code above, but it did not work.
Thanks.

Hang on. The number of significant digits is indeed 5, as given by precision(), so you don't want to use the exponential format. What exactly are you expecting here?

Voted to reopen.  This question is perfectly clear.

@DawoodibnKareem It isn't 'perfectly clear' to me, and it won't be until the OP answers my question. The correct scientific notation for the value shown is 1.2345E-16. The OP needs to explain why he wants something different, which wouldn't be 'scientific notation' at all.

@user207421 Calculator on my Windows 11 shows 1.2345e-6. Which one of us is wrong?

I'm wrong, it is 1.2345E-6. Doesn't affect my other comments. @Abra

Would something like max(scale, precision) > MAX_DIGITS work (you would probably have to add code to handle negative scales)?

Do you mean the number of displayed digits? (Sorry, to me it isn’t perfectly clear.)  I think you will have to count them in the string representation. It’s not that difficult.

Just to clearify my question, despite of being already solved, what I was looking for was just to know how many digits there was after decimal point, not only significant. To then, decide if I need to format in cientific notation or not. Actually, I need to use both aprouches, one for large numbers and the other for small decimal numbers.

You need to use stripTrailingZeros and scale together, like this.
BigDecimal valorSaida = new BigDecimal("0.0000012345").setScale(20);
System.out.println("Scale before stripping: " + valorSaida.scale());
System.out.println("Scale before stripping: " + valorSaida.stripTrailingZeros().scale());

which prints this.
Scale before stripping: 20
Scale before stripping: 10

The scale of the value returned from stripTrailingZeros() will be the number of decimal places that you need, to show all the significant digits.
Obviously that's different from what precision() returns, because it includes the zeros between the decimal point and the significant digits.
